# How can I move the containers to the middle?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering how could I make my containers in line in the middle like my other container? The two containers is the currency converter table and text on the left to it to be in line with the glypicons row icons. As you can see from my codepen the  currency converter table and text on the left to it is more towards the left than equally in the middle.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EmLMwr)

**Two containers I want to be in line with the middle with the glypicons row icons**

```
<!-- Widget Currency Rates Table  & intro text-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h1 class="header1">Currency Converter</h1>
        <p class="para1">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
      </div>
      <br>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div id='gcw_mainFSi25cbHh' class='gcw_mainFSi25cbHh'></div>
          <script>function reloadFSi25cbHh(){ var sc = document.getElementById('scFSi25cbHh');if (sc) sc.parentNode.removeChild(sc);sc = document.createElement('script');sc.type = 'text/javascript';sc.charset = 'UTF-8';sc.async = true;sc.id='scFSi25cbHh';sc.src = 'https://freecurrencyrates.com/en/widget-table?iso=GBPEURJPYAUD&df=2&p=FSi25cbHh&v=fi&source=eucb&width=600&width_title=0&firstrowvalue=1&thm=dddddd,ffffff,dddddd,dddddd,444444,dddddd,ffffff,0073EA,000000&title=Currency%20Converter Table&tzo=-60';var div = document.getElementById('gcw_mainFSi25cbHh');div.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, div);} reloadFSi25cbHh(); </script>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's hard to parse out your intentions from your question, but what I think you mean is. **"How do I change the column width of my columns, so that they take up half the width of the parent container"** Yes? No?

In bootstrap you have a "invisible grid" consisting of 12 "virtual columns". You make a column by using a class like `col-lg-4` or `col-lg-8`. (That's what you have right now. 4+8 = 12 = takes up the whole container). To change the width, try `col-lg-6` + `col-lg-6`, That should make them the same size. Thus:

```
<!-- Widget Currency Rates Table  & intro text-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1 class="header1">Currency Converter</h1>
      <p class="para1">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id='gcw_mainFSi25cbHh' class='gcw_mainFSi25cbHh'></div>
      <script>function reloadFSi25cbHh(){ var sc = document.getElementById('scFSi25cbHh');if (sc) sc.parentNode.removeChild(sc);sc = document.createElement('script');sc.type = 'text/javascript';sc.charset = 'UTF-8';sc.async = true;sc.id='scFSi25cbHh';sc.src = 'https://freecurrencyrates.com/en/widget-table?iso=GBPEURJPYAUD&df=2&p=FSi25cbHh&v=fi&source=eucb&width=600&width_title=0&firstrowvalue=1&thm=dddddd,ffffff,dddddd,dddddd,444444,dddddd,ffffff,0073EA,000000&title=Currency%20Converter Table&tzo=-60';var div = document.getElementById('gcw_mainFSi25cbHh');div.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, div);} reloadFSi25cbHh(); </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(There was a `<br>` tag in there that I removed, because you don't need it!)

Comment: And of course `<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">` on the left column to just shift it to the right instead of changing it's size. It still takes up 6 "virtual" columns in the invisible grid though (since 4+2=6).